# Opencl - single queue with 2 devices

Tags: queue, opencl, bandwidth, migrate

Im trying to port CUDA a test to Opencl. It requires a copy of a buffer from PCIe device-1 onto device-2 of the same type (same brand, same driver etc)

In CUDA it is quite simple: Allocate memory on device-1 and device-2 and copy

In Opencl:
1. Create a context with both devices
2. Allocate memory on a context and associate it with device-1 using migrateMemObject. repeat the same for device-2

- When I create a queue, I need to specify both context and device. So a queue can only be associated with a device and hence can only access memory associated with that device (?)
- Is there a way for 2 devices to use one queue?
- Or is there any way that I can copy from gfx-mem associated with device1 to gfx-mem associated with device2 without copying to main memory?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Only for amd, there is clEnqueueMakeBuffersResidentAMD. Only for nvidia, you can maybe use CUDA again, just to communicate cards, anyway it is hardware-dependent, defying purpose of OpenCL. For using 2 queues in lock-step manner, you should try using events on both queues so that they work depending on each other. You can feed data commands to both independently but run kernels only with events to make them run at the same time or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't associate two devices to one queue. You need two queues for two devices. But... If you read the documentation of [clEnqueueMigrateMemObjects,](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMigrateMemObjects.html) it says:

> Typically, memory objects are implicitly migrated to a device for which enqueued commands, using the memory object, are targeted

In other words, it's the responsibility of the OpenCL runtime to automatically migrate the required buffers to the device where thqy are going to be used.

The question is, is the buffer you want to share between devices read-only or will it be written to by kernels ? If it's read-only than you don't need to bother with any migrations at all, simply enqueue your kernels, and the runtime will copy the buffer once and reuse it. If it's written by kernels from both queues(=devices), then you need to properly order the queued kernels with event dependencies; otherwise the kernels could run in wrong order and the buffer content becomes nonsense.

But in any case, the runtime does the migrations in the background, as efficiently as possible. clEnqueueMigrateMemObjects is useful only as an optimization - if you want to manually overlap memory transfer with kernel execution. I'd focus on getting the application to run reliably before trying any tricks with clEnqueueMigrateMemObjects.

Comment: Hello Huseyin and Mogu, this information is very useful for me. Thanks to both of you. I think I have a few options here which I will explore. Thanks again for your help